# Error repentino layout

Tags: java, android, android-studio

En un proyecto de android, tenía en el `main_activity.xml` la siguiente línea sin que diera ningún error:

```
tools:context="com.example.alumno.prueba_2.Launch" (activity main.xml, carpeta layout dentro de res)
```

pero ahora sí lo da (unresolve launch class) sin que haya cambiado nada para ello. ¿A qué se debe?

Comment: Para que puedas recibir una ayuda más precisa di al menos el error que está dando. La pregunta, tal y como está, es una  pregunta imposible de responder. ¿Puedes mostrar el fragmento completo donde aparece eso?

Comment: Estás diciendo que el contexto de ese elemento está en la clase `Launch`del paquete `prueba_2`, pero esa clase no existe. ¿A qué Activity pertenecería ese elemento?. Como te dije en comentario, sería bueno que pongas el elemento xml completo donde aparece. Si fuese el `MainActivity` debería ser: `tools:context=".MainActivity"`

Comment: ¿Que tiene que ver este problema con "android-studio"?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con lo siguiente:

```
tools:context="ruta_de_tu_actividad_a_la_que_hace_referencia_al_layout"
```

Ejemplo:

```
tools:context="com.example.alumno.prueba_2.LaunchActivity"
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Ahora tienes un error porque el nombre de la clase cambio o el paquete que la contiene.

```
tools:context="com.example.alumno.prueba_2.Launch"
```

- Asegura el nombre de la clase es correcta así como el paquete que la contiene.
- Asegura que la clase sea la que carga el layout mediante `setContentView()`.
- Como otra opción, puedes también eliminar la linea para evitar el problema.